# Ruby Do Multiple Things With Each Element of an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.9.3

I know that I can use

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_array.each {|element| puts element}
```

to do something with each element of an array but what if I need to do several things with each element? It starts complaining when I try to put multiple statements in the block. What I am really looking for is something more like this:

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_array.each |element| do
  #operation one involving the element
  #operation two involving the element
  ...
end
```

Is there any good way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Who is complaining?  You *can* do multiple operations in the block.  What is the error you're seeing?  Do you have a more concrete code example that shows what's generating the error?

Comment: the second chunk should work pretty much as is if you move 'do' to immediately after 'each'

Answer (score 3):

You can put as many statements as you like inside a block, but you need to get the do/end syntax right.

The order is `do |elemenet|`, not `|element| do`. The `do`/`end` keywords replace the `{}`.

```
my_array.each do |element|
  puts "element is #{element}"
  element += 1
  puts "Now element is #{element}"
  # etc...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to cram it into a one liner you can use semicolons.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
x.map{|y| y*=2; y-=5; y}
```

This gives you: 
    => [-3, -1, 1, 3, 5]

It gets pretty ugly pretty fast though, so use multiliners unless there's a really good reason you want it on one line.

Comment: I think there are perfectly valid uses for this